# Rendering After Effects on AWS/GCLOUD and downloading

Tags: aws-lambda, gcloud, after-effects

I’m looking to render a small project with little modifications by code using aerender.exe. I’ve noticed AWS (also gcloud) and the possibility to use it to render the file.

Will it be possible to do such a thing? Meaning:

1. Rendering the project (with variable images and text)
2. After the rendering is done make a working download link

Appreciate your time!